# Pascal Triangle-like Sequence

Tags: geometry, logic

Notice the triangle in which some numeric values were placed on disks.

Knowing that the writing of these values obeys a certain standard and that $ [r \cdot (s + t) + y + 2z] = k$, it is correct to say that the real value of $k$ is

[image]

Answer: 50

It looks like the Pascal triangle

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: In the spirit of the remark by @Schaun, I have proposed to add "like" in your title. Besides, I have changed paschal into Pascal (without "h" and with a capital P, because it is the name of a person).

Comment: @Sullo: *"It looks like the Pascal triangle"* ... Of course, looks can be deceiving; nevertheless ... If it *were* the Pascal triangle, then what values would you get for $r$, $s$, $t$, $y$, and $z$? and what would these yield for $k$?